# How do I change a UIImage color when tapping tableview cell?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

So I have been stuck on this for a day or so. How do I change the color of an UIImage color when tapping on a tableview cell? So for example I have a black image and when I tap a tableview cell it changes that image to white? Thank you!

I tried using this code but I do not know how to implement it right!

```
    let theImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named:"foo")!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate))
theImageView.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Comment: Do you know how to create a custom tableViewCell?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the right pieces but don't know where to call them. You will assign the image to the image view in your `cellForRowAt:` method.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named:"foo")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    return cell
}
```

Then you will change the tint color of the image view in the `didSelect` delegate method.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        cell.imageView.tintColor = newColor
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this! Will I need to create an outlet to an imageView in order for the code I added to work? I also have multiple cells with different images! How would I get each one of them to turn white upon tapping the cell?

Comment: If you are using the default `UITableViewCell` class, then you do not need to make outlets. If you are using a custom table view cell, then yes, you will need to hook up outlets for your custom cells' image views. If your cell has multiple image views, then change the tint color on each image view in the `didSelect` delegate method.

Comment: I am using a default tableview. Can you please add code to show how you would change it for each image? Also the code you entered in cellForRow isn't working. Thank you